# ASP.net C# Silverlight server component and ajax modal inside firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, firefox

I have a modal popup inside of an update panel with a silverlight control.

The video displays fine in IE 7/8 but in firefox all I get is a white screen

I am using the following video skin from [link text](http://sl2videoplayer.codeplex.com/)

```
                <div style="height:360px;">
                <asp:Silverlight
                  ID="myVideoPlayer"
                  runat="server"
                  Source="~/Videos/VideoPlayer.xap" 
                  Width="640px"
                  Height="360px" 
                  InitParameters="m=Efficiency.wmv"
                  Windowless="true" />
                </div>
```

I know it works when I use the normal <object> method but that will not work as I need to set the Initparams from the code behind depending on what video category they choose.

I have consulted the google gods and they have been not so helpful.  Hope you guys can help me with this problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Object tag, and init params injected to aspx like this :

```
<%= initparams %>
```

initparams is protected variable of my Page class:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string initparams;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        initparams = "m=video.asx";
    }
```

you can also change that variable in any event, it will be injected to rendered HTML.

Comment: I have 4 asp button links running the same modal popup.  I dont think that will change something that has been selected after the page loads...or would it?

Comment: don't really understand your first comment, but if it works you can mark it as answered!